# How to implement a system to show Properties of an object // building a game engine

Tags: c++, qt, vector, lambda

I am currently building a game engine.

UML-Diagram:

```
[MainWindow]

[CNode]
   [CNode2D]
       [CSprite2D]
```

Each node has it's own properties (say "name", "width", "height"), where each `node-type` has different properties.

Now, I want to show the properties of my nodes like this (bottom right):

[image: My game engine]

To reach this, I have a `struct` which represents every property like

```
struct propertyTemplate {
    propertyTemplate (QString namei, QString valuei, QString expectedi, bool changedi = false) {
        name = namei;
        value = valuei;
        expected = expectedi;
        changed = changedi;
    }

    QString name;
    QString value;
    QString expected; //What the programm expects;
    bool changed = false; //if these are the default values
};
```

CNode has a `vector of propertyTemplate` which gets filled in the constructor of CSprite2D

```
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Name", getName(), "string"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Sprite-link", "", "link"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Height", "100", "float"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Width", "100", "float"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Position X", "0", "float"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Position Y", "0", "float"));
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Rotation", "0", "string"));
```

When the properties have to be shown, I run this function:

```
void MainWindow::listProperties () {
if (ui->treeWidget_2->currentItem()->text(ui->treeWidget_2->columnAt(100)) == "Sprite2D") {
    CSprite2D *sprite = static_cast< CSprite2D* >(getNodeByName(ui->treeWidget_2->currentItem()->text(ui->treeWidget_2->columnAt(0)))); //gets a pointer to the string judging by nam
    if (sprite == NULL) { //if the return value is NULL

    } else {
        int counter = 0; //counter for the while-loop
        //for ( auto momItem :  propertyItems) delete momItem; //item

        ui->treeWidget_3->clear();
        propertyItems.clear();

        while (counter < sprite->properties.size()) {
            propertyTemplate prop = sprite->properties[counter]; //gets the current item in the property-array

            propertyItems.push_back(new QTreeWidgetItem); //gets filled by the while-loop
            propertyItems[propertyItems.size()-1]->setText(0, prop.name); //sets the text of the item
            propertyItems[propertyItems.size()-1]->setText(1, prop.value);//set the text of the other item
            propertyItems[propertyItems.size()-1]->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsEditable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled | Qt::ItemIsSelectable);;
            ui->treeWidget_3->insertTopLevelItem(ui->treeWidget_3->topLevelItemCount(), propertyItems[propertyItems.size()-1]); //appends the items
            counter ++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The problem: When the user wants to change the property, the program really doesn't know what setter to call, because the `real properties` are stored in variables... The array of propertyTemplate is really much just for showing the properties inside of the QTreeWidget.

My toughts are that you could add a function-pointer when initialising the array, but I wasn't able to because the pointers are inside of a function... I also tried a lambda, but

```
properties.push_back(propertyTemplate("Rotation", "0", "string",[&this] () {setName()};));
```

gave me a compiler-error (I updated the constructor of propertyTemplate therefore, so don't blame the constructor ;))

I already talked to my rubber-duck and friends, and they both told me to use another approach, but I can't think of one better.

ALSO: I'm new to C++/Qt so I might just be the victim of trivial errors. In this case sorry.

Comment: Have you looked at Qt property system: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/properties.html

Comment: "gave me a compiler-error (I updated the constructor of propertyTemplate therefore, so don't blame the constructor ;))" Then give us the compiler error and the updated constructor.

Comment: @BenjaminT Could you pleasy write a complete answer so everyone can see it directly? It seems fine thank you ;)

Comment: @BenjaminT no, I will stick with Qt's properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way. You should really use the Qt property system for a bunch of reasons, but mainly those two:

First and foremost, Qt has the MOC - the meta object compiler, which generates meta information for every object. That information contains the count of properties, their names and so on. You can iterate the properties and access detailed information about them, you can use that to populate your property editor via a model. This way it will work with arbitrary properties for any object, rather than having some static configuration you will have to go back and do for every new type or type change.

Second - for Qt properties you have `QObject::property()` and `QObject::setProperty()` which work in tandem with `QVariant` that will in most cases be able to handle type conversions. So all you need is to have the property name and a `QVariant` holding a compatible value, you don't need to know what setters to call and so on. This makes it significantly easier to get and set property values regardless of their type.

The classes you need to look into are [QMetaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qmetaobject.html) and [QMetaProperty](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/qmetaproperty.html), possibly also [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html) and [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html).

Also, I see you are using GUI elements for data storage, which is a big **NO-NO**. Don't put data in the GUI, you are inviting future trouble. Keep the data in a data layer, and only access that from the GUI. Put the nodes in a vector, then implement a model adapter for that vector, then use model-view-delegate in the GUI.

So the structure should be something like this:

```
node
|
nodes vector                       
|
nodes model <- GUI nodes view <- node delegate  
|
selected node
|
QMetaObject/QMetaProperty query
|
property model <- GUI property view <- property delegate
|
set/get
```

Comment: Well I'm not storing the darta in the QTreeWidget, It gets stored in the class variables AND the array of propertyTemplates ;)

Comment: I'd also suggest you go for a QML implementation, as that would be tremendously faster and easier than doing it in C++.

Comment: What is QML? Is it similar to UML?